# Is it possible to loop different variables with same names but different numbers?

Tags: loops, variables

Basically what i want to do is print the value of 4 variables: x1, x2, x3, x4. Is it possible to do something like an array? I want to do this without putting them into an array because i have a lot of variables, sorta inefficient. Something like this? I know this is a dumb question but i wanted to know if there was a more efficient way to do this :P

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
     System.out.print(x(i));
}
```

Comment: Why not an array? What do you mean with 'inefficient'?

Comment: what language you using, you printing to a web page? or

Comment: This is exactly why you should use an array!

Comment: if it is a list of row in a table, you can just simply tb.FindControl("x" + 1) or tb.FindByElement("x" + 1)

Comment: I have like 100 variables, JCheckBoxes to me exact and seeing as i'm using netbeans' generated and i can't make a JCheckBox [ ] due to deadline shizz and the fact that i can't implement it. I have a bunch of variables with similar names but different numbers so i wanted to see if there was an easier way

Comment: @Tephrite, you try to use parent.FindControl("var" + i) or parent.FindByElementID("var" + i)  for a set of control in another control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is, make your variable as a `List`

```
List<Int> list = new List<Int>();

for(int i = 0; i<list.Count(); i++){
     System.out.print(list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Variable names can't be accessed in such a way. Possibly the area option would be better(and more efficient).